# Boolean subsetting in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Upon learning pandas following 'Pandas for everyone', encounter such an example

```
#+BEGIN_SRC  python :results output  :session
print(scientists)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
                   Name                               Born        Died        Age          Occupation
0     Rosaline Franklin     1920-07-25  1958-04-16   37             Chemist
1        William Gosset        1876-06-13  1937-10-16   61        Statistician
2  Florence Nightingale  1820-05-12  1910-08-13   90               Nurse
3           Marie Curie            1867-11-07  1934-07-04   66             Chemist
4         Rachel Carson        1907-05-27  1964-04-14   56           Biologist
5             John Snow           1813-03-15  1858-06-16   45           Physician
6           Alan Turing            1912-06-23  1954-06-07   41  Computer Scientist
7          Johann Gauss         1777-04-30  1855-02-23   77       Mathematician
```

an operations with booleans

```
#+BEGIN_SRC  python :results output  :session
# boolean vectors will subset rows
print(scientists[scientists['Age'] > scientists['Age'].mean()])
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
:                    Name        Born        Died  Age     Occupation
: 1        William Gosset        1876-06-13  1937-10-16   61   Statistician
: 2  Florence Nightingale  1820-05-12  1910-08-13   90          Nurse
: 3           Marie Curie            1867-11-07  1934-07-04   66        Chemist
: 7          Johann Gauss       1777-04-30  1855-02-23   77  Mathematician
```

Then comes with a confused operation, it states:

> Because of how broadcasting works, if we supply a bool vector that is not
>   the same as the number of rows in the dataframe, the maximum number of rows
>   returned would be the length of the bool vector.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC  python :results output  :session
# 4 values passed as a bool vector
# 3 rows returned
print(scientists.loc[[True, True, False, True]])
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
:     Name                            Born                        Died  Age    Occupation
: 0  Rosaline Franklin  1920-07-25  1958-04-16   37       Chemist
: 1     William Gosset    1876-06-13  1937-10-16   61  Statistician
: 3        Marie Curie        1867-11-07  1934-07-04   66       Chemist
```

The results confused me, what does `[[True, True, False, True]])` mapping to ?

Comment: The format of your data is messed up, can your reformat it so we can actually understand what we are looking at?

Comment: It looks clear that the `[True, True, False, True]` get mapped to the first 4 rows of the data frame, and then it's just normal boolean indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you pass boolean mask by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - rows are filtered by boolean Series, list or array - only rows with `True` are returned - so in your data with index `0,1,3`.

After test in pandas 0.24+ if number of rows is higher like number of values in boolean mask it working with no error:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(6)}) 
print (df1)
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5

print(df1.loc[[True, True, False, True]])
   a
0  0
1  1
3  3
```